# Do (or can) hydrogen bonds between water molecules neutralize their own polarity?

Tags: water, physical-chemistry

Do (or can) hydrogen bonds between water molecules neutralize their own polarity as indicated here:
Hydrogen bonding as the mechanism that neutralizes $\mathrm{H_2 O}$ polarity

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sci.physics/Cin1MQ4ZyFU/QmNEM9mnDgAJ
or
 https://zenodo.org/record/37224

Disclaimer: I am author of this paper.

Comment: You obviously wrote a controversial paper on polarity in water. After discussions at google groups, which leave many questions on your theory open, you ask the community here to help you justify your arguments?

Comment: After reading your paper I agree on one point - it is a unique perspective.

Comment: Water is unique.  My paper describes why.  I am not surprised by your inability to dispute it. In so doing you reveal the ineptitude of conventional theory. But that isn't necessary in that conventional theory has thus far--and despite no shortage of resources--failed miserably to reconcile the numerous anomalies of H2O, preferring, instead, to arrogantly dismiss them, hiding behind the perceived validity of their model instead of addressing arguments directly and, thereby, exposing the shortcomings of conventional misthinking.

Comment: "After discussions at google groups, which leave many questions on your theory open, . . . "

Comment: "We deal with mainstream physics here. Questions about the general correctness of unpublished personal theories are off topic, although specific questions evaluating new theories in the context of established science are usually allowed. For more information, see Is non mainstream physics appropriate for this site?." – David Z

Comment: I'm only concerned with what is correct.  If this site wishes to only parrot back what is "mainstream" then you make yourself irrelevant to scientific progress.

Comment: If the sissies at this site can't deal with controversial issues you render yourselves irrelevant and boring.

Comment: @David Z: "We deal with mainstream physics here.
JMcG: The fact that H2O has over 70 recognized anomalies is mainstream. This means that there are over 70 different observations about H2O that THE MAINSTREAM recognizes as being inconsistent with current theory.  So, I suggest you take your arrogant attitude and apply it to some genuinely phoney science, like climate change.

James McGinn / Solving Tornadoes
http://www.thunderbolts.info/forum/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=16329&start=165#p122133